# Not making a network call in case of Hazelcaste cache miss

Tags: caching, hazelcast

I have enabled hazelcast near cache for one of my application. I case if cache miss from near cache Hazelcast is making a network call to look for the data. 
The behaviour I am looking for is, in case of cache miss from "near cache" no network call should be made. 
Any idea how to achieve that with Hazelcast?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in Hazelcast, at least I wouldn't know of any way. What is the reason you want to prevent it to call down to the cluster, I mean Near-Cache is a speed optimization (at the tradeoff of consistency) but not a full blown local cache. Maybe looking at the Continuous Query Cache would solve your issue, but I don't have enough information about your use case to understand your need :-)